# GIMP Bucket ignores saturation value

Tags: gimp, fill

I need to fill the red area with white colour. As you can see the foreground is very very white shade of pure red. Why do I get fully saturated red instead (the left circle)? Only when I go to the extreme and select a pure white, which is actually my goal, I suddenly get some dark grey (the right circle). This is frustrating, pls help. :-)

I also can't figure out why can't I just select a layer, then a bucket, and change the white background to something else? Only when I draw something on that layer, then I can change the colour of this to something else but not the white background.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the left menu, change the blend **Mode** for the bucket fill to **Normal**.

[image]

Comment: Was there a specific reason why this had been set differently? Normal is the default, and just trying a bucket fill with that mode would have gotten the expected result.

Comment: There was no reason, I had no idea what different modes do, I might have changed it by accident.